# Rx: How to cancel call?

Tags: android, rx-java

For example we have a call:

```
getObsevable()
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe(::onSuccess, ::onError))
```

Is there is a way to not launch it if condition is true? For example:

```
getObsevable()
.stop({ Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MINUTE) % 2 == 0 })
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe(::onSuccess, ::onError))
```

In this code I mean we should not launch observable if current minute is odd. And launch it if current minute is even.

Comment: Does something prevent you from wrapping inside an `if` statement?

Comment: @JensV sure, I can. But described way is more flexible as I think. If I have a lot of simular calls in my application I can manage it from one place.

Comment: @AntonisRadz No, it looks like "cancel until it running". I need "do not start it if condition is true".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `filter` to achieve this. So what happens when filter is used, if the condition doesn't meet, the stream below doesn't get executed.

In your case (or example), if the current minute is odd, the subscribe method wont be called. However, if it's even, the stream will work just the way it's written.

```
getObservable()
    .filter({ Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MINUTE) % 2 == 0 })
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(::onSuccess, ::onError))
```

You can read about it here -> http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/filter.html

Answer (score 0):

Assign it to a disposable, and dispose it before start another call, or wherever you need to dispose it

```
Disposable disposable;


public void createDisposableWithMyObservable(){
    if(disposable != null) disposable.dispose();

    disposable = getObsevable()
                   .stop({ Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MINUTE) % 2 == 0 })
                   .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                   .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                   .subscribe(::onSuccess, ::onError));
}
```